# How can I consume Spring Hateoas embedded?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest, spring-hateoas

I am studying Spring Projects (Web, Security, DATA JPA, Hateoas)

And I am developing sample web service.

It is consist of two module.

1. Rest API server (provide data, Spring Data JPA, Spring Data Rest, Spring Hateoas)
2. Web server (provide Web service, Spring MVC, Spring Security)

Actually "Rest API server" is simple and easy.

I just defined some Entity class, and just use "@RepositoryRestResource"
@RepositoryRestResource generated RestController, right?

So when I call REST API like "localhost:8080/users", I can receive the responses.

But there is very critical issue.

I got the response like below:

```
{
"_links":{
    "self":{
        "href": "http://localhost:8888/users{?page,size,sort}",
        "templated": true
    },
    "search":{
        "href": "http://localhost:8888/users/search"
    }
},
"_embedded":{
    "users":[
    {
        "email": "test@gmail.com", "name": null, "isShowName": null, "nickName": null
    }
    ]
},
"page":{
    "size": 20,
    "totalElements": 5,
    "totalPages": 1,
    "number": 0
}
}
```

When I print the response as toString, there are no "Embedded" values.

There are just "link" values.

I need the "Embedded" values.

I tried to googling, but there are no clear resolutions.

So I am contemplating using not Hateoas but RestController.

If I use RestController, I can resolve this easily.

Who can help me please?